# How do you add an editable block of text inside a non editable block in Quill?

Tags: javascript, quill

I want to have an editable block of text inside a non-editable block. I registered a `contenteditable` attribute to Quill and added my custom `span` Inline blot. When I insert something like `<p contenteditable="false">text0<span contenteditable="true">text1 </span>text2</p>` as html it returns `text2` inside `span contenteditable="true"` while it should be non-editable.

Steps for Reproduction:
Open https://jsfiddle.net/dertcmak/x7pmc24q/16/

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Ended up with this solution: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dertcmak/x7pmc24q/82/). 
Had to overwrite `format` method in my custom `Span`.